# SQL - Changing " or ' in SQL so adding text is easier

Tags: mysql, sql, import, delimiter

So I am building a database of all my text messages to get information about my habits and I'm having trouble importing the contents of the messages. Whenever there are apostrophes (often) or quotation marks (not as rare as you might think), I get syntax issues.

Is there a way to make MySQL use something other than " or ' to encase strings (specifically, the field is a VARCHAR). If I could use a ~ or some other rarely used character in text messaging my life would become a whole lot easier.

Comment: If you would use prepared statements with placeholders, then you wouldn't have to care about it. I'm sure the API you're using would provide these. And no: MySQL has got even more than the SQL standard. The standard is single quotes only.

Comment: What do you mean "prepared statements with placeholders"?

Comment: Do you write every SQL statement by hand? Typically one uses a programming language like Java, Perl, PHP, Python, ... to communicate with a database.

Comment: I'm just starting work on the database and java GUI. I think I see what you mean though. I'll want to handle the parsing over on the Java side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably you should use parameterised queries, then your database connector takes care of sending the strings to the database in the correct way.

If you need to build the queries by concatenating the values into a query, you need to escape the strings correctly to make them string literals in the SQL code.

Stick to one delimiter for strings, don't use apostrophes around some strings and qoutation marks around others, that only makes it harder to escape them correctly. I suggest that you use apostrophes, as that is what the SQL standard specifies.

To escape the strings correctly to be a string literal delimited by apostropes, you should:

- Replace all backslashes by double backslashes, then
- Replace all apostrophes by a backslash and an apostrophe

For example, to make the string `It's an "example" with a backslash(\).` into a string literal, it should end up like this in a query:

```
insert into Table (txt) values ('It\'s an "example" with a backslash(\\).')
```

Note: This is a correct way to escape strings for MySQL. Other databases may use different characters for escaping and need other characters to be escaped, so using this for any other database may fail, or even worse open up for SQL injection attacks.